# How to change img src link mouse hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

HTML

```
<div module="product_listnormal">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" class="{$product_compare_class} {$product_compare_display|display}">
                <div id="prdImgWrapper">
                     <a href="/product/detail.html{$param}" class="prdImg"><img src="{$image_medium}" alt="" class="prdImgImg"/></a>
                </div>
.....
```

So i Add onmouseover in img tag

```
<a href="/product/detail.html{$param}" class="prdImg"><img src="{$image_medium}" onmouseover="this.src={$image_medium} + 'aaa'" alt="" class="prdImgImg"/></a>
```

but it doesn't call `{$image_medium}aaa link what's wrong?`

ex) `if $image_medium = 111.png
$image_medium + aaa = 111aaa.png`

Comment: its not possible with CSS, you will have to use Javascript

Comment: can you give me little help for use Javascript?

Comment: are you asking like this, http://jsfiddle.net/epHjY/1150/

Comment: Why don't you use `background-image` in CSS on the link? It's just one more line in CSS to also add another background for the hover state.

Comment: @Paul becuase that is not just one image that mouse over link need 200 image :( so i need to use VALIABLE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use on mouse over and on mouse leave function like this

```
onmouseover='this.src = this.src.replace(".jpg","_2.jpg")' onmouseleave='this.src = this.src.replate("_2.jpg", ".jpg")'
```

this source can use every picture

Answer (score 0):

You have two links image_medium and image_medium2.

Say image_medium="a.jpg" and image_medium_2="a_2.jpg";

**Using pure JavaScript**

1) You can add listener for the same using mouseenter and mouseleave events if you know values

```
var divToBeHovered=document.getElementById("prdImgWrapper");
//add listener

divToBeHovered.addEventListener("mouseenter",function(){

      var imgEle=document.querySelector("#"+this.id+" img");
      imgEle.src="a_2.jpg"; //image_medium_2

},false);

divToBeHovered.addEventListener("mouseleave",function(){

      var imgEle=document.querySelector("#"+this.id+" img");
      imgEle.src="a.jpg"; //image_medium

},false);
```

2)If you don't know values i.e src of image is dynamic then you can create one function and call it both on mouseenter and mouseleave event.

```
<a href="/product/detail.html{$param}" class="prdImg">
<img src="{$image_medium}" 
onmouseenter="changeURLOfImage(this,'{$image_medium}aaa')" 
onmouseleave="changeURLOfImage(this,'{$image_medium}')"
mouseralt="" class="prdImgImg"/></a>

function changeURLOfImage(imageElem,url){

    imageElem.src="url"

}
```

3)Assign direct values to src

```
<img onmouseenter='this.src ={$image_medium}aaa' onmouseleave='this.src ={$image_medium}'/>
```

Comment: but how to get VALUE ?  imgEle.src={image_medium}; like this?

Comment: What is value of {image_medium}

Comment: {$image_medium} is may be the dyanamic value coming from the server

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using pure CSS by using two images and changing the display on hover state.

```css
a.prdImg > img {
  display: inline-block;
}
a.prdImg > img + img {
  display: none;
}
a.prdImg:hover > img {
  display: none;
}
a.prdImg:hover > img + img {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div module="product_listnormal">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" class="{$product_compare_class} {$product_compare_display|display}">
                <div id="prdImgWrapper">
                     <a href="/product/detail.html{$param}" class="prdImg"><img src="http://media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/65/7e/a2/657ea254eb522135fbd59e0656a2e1dd.jpg" alt="" class="prdImgImg"/><img src="http://baconmockup.com/400/300" alt="" class="prdImgImg"/></a>
                </div>
.....
```

By the way; wouldn't cause `this.src={$image_medium} + 'aaa'` the src to change from `111.png` to `111.pngaaa`?

Answer (score 0):

While changing image src is not possible with css you can have 2 images(one hidden) and a container and on container mouse hover hide first image and show the second image.
something like this:

Html:

```
<div>
    <span>This could be an image</span>
    <span>This could be an image</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
 }
div span{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:none;
    background-color:red;
 }
div span:first-child{
    display:block;
    background-color:lime;

}
div:hover span:first-child{
    display:none;
 }
div:hover span:nth-child(2){
     display:block;
}
```

have a look:
http://jsfiddle.net/mzvaan/fs6mc952/

Answer (score 0):

## html code like

```
 <img src="sample1.png" id="newimg">
```

## script like this

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#newimg").hover(function() {
        $("#newimg").attr('src', 'sample2.png');
        })
});
```